# How can I use"$timeout" in factory using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript

I have the services and within particular time duration if response is come than ok, other wise show error in popup.

Here is my service code:

```
angular.module('server', [])

.factory('api', function($http) {
    var server = "http://myapi-nethealth.azurewebsites.net";
        return {
            //Login
            login : function(formdata) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: server + '/Users/Login',
                    data: $.param(formdata),
                    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                })
            },
        };

    });
```

Please tell me how can I use timeout property in services.

Comment: try to use `timeout` option from `$http` API https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: How can I put pop after time out, I have to put in controller or service only...

Comment: RTFM "Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http specific methods: success and error." you just need `$http({your options}).success(function(){alert('success')}).error(function(){alert('error')})`

Comment: I don'y know how use the promise, I am using the services in the simple way that I have post in question, can you please tell me how can I use this in my code.....I am new to angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Read this post - [How to set a global http timeout in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs)

Where you can set a timeout for your http calls.

You can inject the above factory in your controller and then make a call with success and error callbacks like below

```
api.login(formdata)
.success(function(){ alert("success"); })
.error(function(){ alert("error"); });
```