# Forcing an http request to timeout from frontend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, frontend

I am making a single page application using angular, at times the backend services do not response or are down and browser takes very long time to timeout request.

How can I forcefully timeout an http request from frontend in lesser time, this will help me show message to user that backend is not responding.

Comment: Since you tagged your question "angularjs", maybe have a look at http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

`$http` config has a `timeout` property that you can set when making a request with `$http`.

If you want to get something done at global level for all `$http` can look at this SO post [How to set a global http timeout in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs)

Comment: Hi...I tried these options, but somehow they are not helping to force timeout.