# Angular timeout is not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have tried below code on different ways using angualrjs.but there is no reflection on connection timeout in request header as well as application flow.i have went through many angular js sites. but no output.

```
   angular.module('MyApp', [])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
     }]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a global http timeout in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs)

Comment: yeah, even i went through that link also..but unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're writing to the wrong object (`defaults` instead of `defaults.headers`).

> The defaults can also be set at runtime via the $http.defaults object
>   in the same fashion. For example:

```
module.run(function($http) {  
   $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w' });
}
```

from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Try to do it this way.

Or when your request is sent (same source as before a few lines below):

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

Comment: have you tried this one??. can u able to see the reflection of the above code in your connection requets header..

Comment: but in angular js the global way of setting connection timeout is looks like
angular.module('MyApp', [])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
     }]);

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. You have an open project, so it should be easy to change. Provide the full running code of your example and I try it out myself.

Comment: u can get the sample url.just try to hit that service with your requested timeout.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/adnan-i/5014277 i hope this would be fine. let me try this one.. but it's look like hardcoding the value.