# Make sure that a web service call fails if it is not getting response

Tags: angularjs, web-services, http, angularjs-service

I am trying to call a webservice. I want that if  i am not getting response from web service in 10 sec then the service call should fail and show the error message in .error section.
I tried passing timeout in http call but that is not working for mobile phones.
My service call is like this-

```
    $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            *timout:10000,*
            headers: {
                      'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                      'Encoding':"UTF-8",
                      'devicemetadata':devicemetadata
                      },
            data: inputData,
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
                    }
         })
.success(function(response){
          console.log("loginServiceSuccess:"+JSON.stringify(response));
          def.resolve(response);
          })
.error(function(msg){
            console.log("loginServiceFailure"+msg);
            def.reject(msg);
          });
```

Timeout is not working for mobile phones.
I want that if service does not give response in 10sec .error block should be executed...any solution?

Comment: check this [asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15020611/3033318) please

Comment: just wondering about the line : *timout:10000,* above. I guess you added the * to mark the line. Without these there is a typo, it should be timeout:10000,

Comment: These stars are just to highlight,timeout is working good in browser but not in mobile phone/ionic applications.