# angularJS AJAX requests default timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

What is the default timeout set for any kind of AngularJS AJAX calls (`$http`, `$resource` or `Restangular`)? Is *no timeout* the default one, meaning that, as long as the connection with the server is alive & the server didn't respond yet - there would be no timeout?

Does this differ anyhow from native JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object behavior?

I tried to find it, but all I found was how to set timeout for an explicit $http call.

Comment: Have you tried [How to set a global http timeout in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs)?

Comment: this is what I wrote... I'm not interested in setting the timeout - neither for a single request nor globally. I want to know what is the default angularJS (or native JavaScript) behavior in terms of timeout. Without any alterations. Perhaps I'm trying to look in a wrong place, but I would appreciate someone to clarify this to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setting timeout headers in http request.