# Angular POST gets net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when server takes 3 mins to finish

Tags: angularjs

Hi i run into this problem, did search online but cannot find exact answer yet.

Basically i'm doing a POST from web client, node.js server will pick it up and starts to execute the command.

If it works, this command (say my_cmd 1234) finishes within 30 seconds, and angular gets the response and updates the status in the webpage.

Now if i pass in an different for this command (my_cmd 2345), it takes 3 minutes to finish, i did run this by hand in the linux console. After 3 minutes it does finish and prints out status message. But Angular POST returns net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

So is there a default timeout value i should set ? Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a global http timeout in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs)

Comment: No, cannot make it work yet, but many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually i changed the timeout value in the server side and it worked.
I followed this.
[How to modify the nodejs request default timeout time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925284/how-to-modify-the-nodejs-request-default-timeout-time)