# Add Delay in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I want to add some delay in angularjs. So that it can fetch data from api. Because my api is heavy. I am calling this function. Basically i want some delay to load page so that my api work properly. I tried some time my data pull immediate some time i am getting error. When i refresh my page it work fine.

```
      Help to put $timeout function in this angularjs
  // Geting test stuff
    $scope.teststuff = function () {
$scope.loading = true;
$http.get(settings.WebApiBaseUrl + 'Api/testing')           
   .success(function (data) {
        $scope.mydata = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Error " + status )             
  $scope.loading = false;
    })
```

}

Comment: you can increase service timeout as per your requirement;

Comment: why do u want delay ..I believe your teststuff function will get called immediately when page loads !

Comment: Adding arbitrary `$timeout` delays is a terrible way to cope with async code.  Use a resolved Promise to control when the code depending on the AJAX call runs, or design your components such that they can cope with empty data while the ajax call is still in progress.

Comment: You should use a promise...

Comment: whats the use-case for the delay

Comment: In my api, i have lot of stuff. Sometime it load immediately and some time its showing error. That why i am thinking to using delay function, So i can remove my error.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

This problem can easily be solved by using `resolve property of $routerProvider`. Please use this config. So here the route `/ed` will not load until the resolve is completed, meaning the http request must return a value, only after that the page will load.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    var settings.WebApiBaseUrl =  "some url you want to use";
    $routeProvider.when("/al", { templateUrl: "Views/test.html", controller: "testCtrl" })
  .when("/ed", { 
    templateUrl: "Views/test2.html", 
    controller: "test2Ctrl",
    resolve: {
        initialize: function($http, $sessionStorage){
            $http.get('api/ApiKey/' + $sessionStorage.user)
          .success(function (myKey) { 
            return $http.get(settings.WebApiBaseUrl + 'Api/test1', { headers: { 'X-ApiKey': myKey } })
            .success(function (data) { 
              return data; 
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
              alert("error" + status);
            });
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
             alert("error" + status);
          }); 
        }
    }
  })
  .otherwise({ 
    redirectTo: '/al' 
  }); 
}]);
```

Now in the controller you need to do.

```
app.controller( 'test2Ctrl', function ( $scope, initialize ) {
        $scope.loading=false;
        $scope.test1=initialize;
        $scope.loading=true;
});
```

**Old Answer:**
so you have a http request which is a promise and will wait until the data is received and from your example I can see you are implementing a loading screen kind of thing until the http request is completed.

To ensure the bulky http request doesn't time out you can use.

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
}]);
```

While the page waits for the http request to complete you can use the scope variable(`$scope.loading = true;`) to activate a loading spinner library to mask your page. Checkout [angular loading overlay](http://bsalex.github.io/angular-loading-overlay/_site/) or some other code to do this.

Reference:
[http timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015416/how-to-set-a-global-http-timeout-in-angularjs)

Comment: I want to delay every single call (endpoint)? When they are called.

Comment: If you have an $http request it uses promises to wait for the data to be received so there is no need for setting the delay, are you using any angular router (ui-router) in you application? The line I have given will increase the wait time for the HTTP request, I gave this because I thought the request is getting timed out.

Comment: @DeveshKhosla angular has a $routeprovider service, there you can place your http request in a resolve parameter, the page will not load until the http request is completed. http://embed.plnkr.co/kHXK54 also http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: Same problem. Actually I have problem with APIKey. Some time my APIKey work fine some time it give me error 401. That's why i was thinking to put some delay. But still same problem

Comment: @DeveshKhosla you are in the wrong approach, delay will only worsen your code quality, please share your angular routing config, if possible share your code, I will show what's wrong.

Comment: app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        
        $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
        $routeProvider
        .when("/al", {
                templateUrl: "Views/test.html",
                controller: "testCtrl"
            })
        .when("/ed", {
                templateUrl: "Views/test2.html",
                controller: "test2Ctrl"
            })
               
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/al' });

    }])

Comment: @DeveshKhosla can you please try out the code in my updated answer.

Comment: My code is really big. one of Controller shows here.                                   // Get all test1
    $http.get('api/ApiKey/' + $sessionStorage.user).success(function (myKey) {
        $http.get(settings.WebApiBaseUrl + 'Api/test1', {
            headers: {      'X-ApiKey': myKey   }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.test1 = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             alert("error" + status)
        })          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { scope.loading = false;
    });

Comment: @DeveshKhosla I updated again, try this, also please start reading on angular router resolve, it will clarify your doubt.

Comment: @DeveshKhosla any luck solving this issue?

Comment: Thanks. My server was having error that time. Thank you so much for you help. Really appreciated.